# all valid combinations of n-pair of parenthesis

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a js program to print all valid combinations of `n` pairs of parentheses, eg:

`(), (()()),(())`.

Can you tell me whether this is correct or not?

https://jsfiddle.net/e7mcp6xb/

```
module.exports = Parentheses = (function() {
  var _isParenthesesMatch = function(str) {
    var parentheses = str.length;
    var rightParentheses = '(';
    var leftParentheses = ')';
    var rightCount = 0;
    var leftCount = 0;

    for(i=0;i<=str.length;i++){
       if(rightParentheses == str.charAt(i))
       {
          rightCount++;
       }
       else if(leftParentheses == str.charAt(i))
       {
          leftCount++;
       }
    }

    if(rightCount == leftCount){
      return true;
    }
    else(rightCount != leftCount){
      return false;
    }

  }
  
}());
```

Answer (score 7):

The check is wrong, but You can fix it easily: In each step of the `for` loop the number of opening parenthesis cannot be smaller than the number of closing ones:

```
if (rightCount < leftCount)
    return false;
```

The whole function should look like this:

```
function(str) {
    var rightParentheses = '(';
    var leftParentheses = ')';
    var rightCount = 0;
    var leftCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
       if (rightParentheses == str.charAt(i))
          rightCount++;
       else if (leftParentheses == str.charAt(i))
          leftCount++;

       if (rightCount < leftCount)
          return false;
    }

    return rightCount == leftCount;
}
```

If You'd like to generate all valid strings, you can use this function:

```
function nPair(n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return [""];

    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

        var lefts = nPair(i);
        var rights = nPair(n - i - 1);

        for (var l = 0; l < lefts.length; ++l)
            for (var r = 0; r < rights.length; ++r)
                result.push("(" + lefts[l] + ")" + rights[r]);
    }

    return result;
}

// result of nPair(3):
// ["()()()", "()(())", "(())()", "(()())", "((()))"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is wrong, try checking if left and right parenthesis and balanced:

```
function isValid(str){
  var stripedStr = str.replace(/[^\(\)]+/g, '');

  return stripedStr.split('').reduce(function(a, b){
    return a > -1 ? b === '(' ? a + 1 : a - 1 : -1;
  }, 0) === 0;
}
```

- `stripedStr` - use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove any characters that are not `(` or `)`.
- [`split('')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) - returns an array so we can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).
- [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) has to reduce it to a single value.

  - The reduce starts with 0 as initial value and in the reduce function we count parenthesis
    (`+1` for `(`, `-1` for `)` )
  - Our string is valid if our counter never goes below `0` and we end up with `0`.

---

You can write the reduce function like this too:

```
function(previousValue, currentValue){
  if (previousValue > -1){
    if (currentValue === '('){
      return previousValue + 1;
    } else {
      return previousValue - 1;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
function(a, b){
  return a > -1 ? b === '(' ? a + 1 : a - 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your email your code is compicated can you explain it more so that I can understand...

Comment: I'm using one counter, left parenthesis = +1, right parenthesis = -1,
if the counter equals -1 or does not equal 0 at the end the string is invalid.

Comment: Sure. It removes any characters that are not `(` or `)`.

Comment: can u comment other lines in code...its so difficult for me to understand...pleas help...

Comment: I did not understand this line....can you replace with simple if and else... return a > -1 ? b === '(' ? a + 1 : a - 1 : -1;

Comment: is it possible to edit in my code so that I can understand better https://jsfiddle.net/e7mcp6xb/

Comment: I suppose you'll understand better if you'll edit your code your self.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i have modified your code a little bit. Modification and its explanation is marked in comments.

```
module.exports = Parentheses = (function() {
  var _isParenthesesMatch = function(str) {
    var parentheses = str.length;
    var rightParentheses = '(';
    var leftParentheses = ')';
    var count=0;

    for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        //this is to check valid combination start always from ( and end with )
            if(str.charAt(0)==rightParentheses && str.length-1==leftParentheses) 
            {
               if(rightParentheses == str.charAt(i))
               {
                  count++;  //this will calculate how many times rightParentheses is present & increment count by 1
               }
               else if(leftParentheses == str.charAt(i))
               {
                  count--;  //this will simply decrement count to match valid sequence
               }
            }

            if(count==0){
              return true;
            }


  }

}());
```

Answer (score -1):

It is wrong, because your function will return true for this example ))(( or this ())(()