# Calculating the complexity of algorithm to print all valid (i.e., properly opened and closed) combinations of n-pairs of parentheses

Tags: python, algorithm, catalan

I would like your opinion on the time and space complexity of this algorithm I implemented (in Python) to calculate the complexity of algorithm to print all valid (i.e., properly opened and closed) combinations of n-pairs of parentheses (see [all valid combinations of n-pair of parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321063/all-valid-combinations-of-n-pair-of-parenthesis))

```
def find_par_n(n):
    s = set(["()"])
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        set_to_add = set()
        for str_ in s:
            set_temp = set()
            ana = set()
            for j in range(len(str_) + 1):
                str_c = str_[0:j] + '(' + str_[j:]
                if str_c in ana:
                    continue
                ana.add(str_c)
                for k in range(j + 1, len(str_) + 1):
                    str_a = str_c
                    str_a = str_a[0:k] + ')' + str_a[k:]
                    set_temp.add(str_a)
            set_to_add.update(set_temp)
        s = set_to_add
    return s
```

Most likely the algorithm can be improved in terms of time and space. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: i'm afraid of touching it, i don't want to ruin it. :P

Comment: Would `n` represent the number of parentheses pairs, `()` be `n=1`, `(())` be `n=2`, `(()())` be `n=3`, etc.? Or is it in terms of depth, like `()` is `n=1`, `(())` is `n=2`, `((()())())` is `n=3`?

Comment: @bcdan Doesn't matter for `O(n)`, because, all proper strings with `n` pairs are of (character) length `2n`.

Comment: @dhke I was asking because I was writing improved code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try with a simpler version instead.

Some theorems:

1. Properly paired string are of even length. Don't ask me to prove this one, please.
2. Given a properly paired string of length `2k`, it is possible to construct all strings of length `2(k + 1)` by inserting pairs of parenthesis `'()'` at every possible location within the string. There are `2k + 1` such positions.
3. To generate all `n` pairs, we need to recursive into the insertion step `n` times (and get strings of length `2n`.

Note that this is not enough to generate all *unique* properly paired strings, because e.g. inserting `()` into `()` yields the same string twice (`()()`). However as an upper bound it should suffice.

```
def add_parens(s, nparens):    
    if not s:    
       add_parens('()', nparens)    
    max_length = 2 * nparens    
       if len(s) == max_length:    
       print(s)    
    else:    
        for i in range(0, len(s)):    
            add_parens(s[0:i] + '()' + s[i:], nparens)    

n = 5      
add_parens('', n)
```

Time complexity:

1. There is `1` insertion point for the empty string.
2. There are `3` insertion points for `()`.
   ...

So all in all:

```
T(n) = 1 * 3 * ... * 2n + 1 ~ O(n!)
```

Space complexity for the recursive version is `O(n(2n + 1))`, however I'm pretty sure it is possible to bring this down to linear.

Comment: Thanks, your comment makes a lot of sense. So do you think you can't do better than factorial for this problem?

Comment: @agave1987 No, every correctly paired string is a [*Dyck Word*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language) and the number of Dyck Words over a set of symbols is a [*Catalan Number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics), hence you're stuck with `n!` time complexity as there are simply that many combinations.

Answer (score 1):

For optimal results, avoid sets. If you generate each possibility exactly once, you can just put them into a vector.

Here's a very simple recursion which is slightly slower than @bcdan's answer:

```
def rget(n):
  if n == 0:
    return ['']
  else:
    return [fst + '(' + snd + ')' for i in range(n)
                                  for fst in rget(i)
                                  for snd in rget(n-i-1)]
```

If you wanted a generator rather than a complete list of results, a variant of the above is probably ideal, but for the case of a complete list, it's quite a bit faster to compute the results of each j from 0 to n, using the previously computed lists instead of a recursive call:

```
def iget(n):
  res = [['']]
  for j in range(1, n+1):
    res.append([fst + '(' + snd + ')' for i in range(j)
                                      for fst in rget(i)
                                      for snd in rget(j-i-1)])
  return res[n]
```

This turns out to be an order of magnitude faster (using Python 3.3.2).

#### Why it works

You can decompose any balanced string into two balanced substrings. This is not a unique decomposition, but it can be made unique by choosing the shortest possible non-empty balanced suffix. The shortest nonempty balanced suffix has the property that the starting `(` matches the closing `)`; if that were not the case, it could be decomposed into two shorter non-empty balanced sequences. So the recursive consists of finding all sequences of the form `Fst(Snd)` where the sum of the sizes of *Fst* and *Snd* is *n*-1.

#### Time complexity:

The number of balanced sequences with *n* pairs of parentheses is the *n*<sup>th</sup> [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) C<sub>*n*</sub>, which is O(4<sup>*n*</sup>*n*<sup>2/3</sup>). The above code generates each sequence in O(*n*) (because the string concatenation takes O(*n*) time) for a total complexity of O(4<sup>*n*</sup>*n*<sup>5/3</sup>)

Comment: I like this solution because it does not generate the duplicates that the bottom-up construction via insertion does. Bottom up (to me) seems a little easier to understand, though, but that is maybe because of the fact that it drops the uniqueness constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I got curious and wrote my own version. Here are some specs (this is all in **Python 2.7**):

## `n=8`

Mine: 21 ms

Yours: 89 ms

## `n=10`

Mine: 294 ms

Yours: 1564 ms

```
def get(n):
    
    def find(current):
        out = []
        last_index = 0
        for j in range(current.count('(')):
            last_index = current.index('(',last_index) + 1
            out.append(current[:last_index] + '()' + current[last_index:])
        return out
        
    seed = '()'
    current = '()'
    temp = set(['()'])
    for i in range(n):
        new = set()
        for thing in temp:
            new.update(find(thing))
        temp = new

    return [a[1:-1] for a in temp]
```

I think the biggest difference is that mine only has 3 for loops, and yours has 4. This happens at the `str.count` function. Using this built-in probably contributes significantly to speed. Also, after each stage I identified duplicates, and this cuts down exponentially on time.

Actually, the biggest difference I see is that I only insert *after* parenthesis, and then strip the outer two when it is finished. It creates way fewer duplicates. So `((())())` is created, and reduced to its correct form of `(())()` after removing the enclosing `()`.

Comment: I also identify duplicates using the 'ana' set. I think that my ex. time is worse because of the many sets I use...

Comment: @agave1987 I don't know exactly what the time difference is caused by. Probably some combination of the factors I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive version seems to be very simple and it spends time only on valid branches:

```
def gen(sofar, l, r, n):
    """
    sofar: string generated so far
    l: used left parentheses
    r: used right parentheses
    n: total required pairs
    """
    result = []
    if l == n and r == n:
        # solution found
        result.append(sofar)
    else:
        if l > r:
            # can close
            result.extend(gen(sofar + ")", l, r + 1, n))
        if l < n:
            # can open
            result.extend(gen(sofar + "(", l + 1, r, n))
    return result

def generate(n):
    return gen("", 0, 0, n)

print generate(4)
```

Comment: Very nice code, thanks. What do you think the complexity of this code is?

Comment: @dlask I already tried a recursive solution, and even though it is simpler, it takes a _lot_ more time to run. Not that I am judging yours. It is very different from mine, but please time it against the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

The number of possible combinations is the Catalan Number.
So the complexity is at least the one specified by that number.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number