# Algorithm to print all valid combinations of n pairs of parentheses

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

This is a very popular interview question and there are tons of pages on the internet about the solution to this problem.
eg. [Calculating the complexity of algorithm to print all valid (i.e., properly opened and closed) combinations of n-pairs of parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479647/calculating-the-complexity-of-algorithm-to-print-all-valid-i-e-properly-opene)

*So before marking this as a duplicate question please read the full details.*

I implemented my own solution to this problem but I'm missing some edge cases that I'm having a hard time to figure out.

```
def get_all_parens(num):    
    if num == 0:
        return []
    if num == 1:
        return ['()']
    else:
        sub_parens = get_all_parens(num - 1)
        temp = []
        for parens in sub_parens:
            temp.append('(' + parens + ')')
            temp.append('()' + parens)
            temp.append(parens + '()')
        return set(temp)
```

there is basically a recursive call to subproblems and putting parenthesis around the combinations from subproblem.

For `num = 4`, it returns 13 possible combinations however the correct answer is 14, and the missing one is `(())(())`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. is this a right direction I'm moving towards or it's a completely wrong approach?

For the first time reader here is the question:
Implement an algorithm to print all valid (e.g., properly opened and closed) combinations of n pairs of parentheses.
E.G Input: 3, Output: ()()(), ()(()), (())(), (()()), ((()))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a wrong approach.

As you can see in your failure case `(())(())` your algorithm may only obtain such string by placing parenthesis around `())(()`. Unfortunately the latter is not a valid combination, and cannot be generated: the prior recursive call only builds valid ones.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to correct in your approach.

1. recursion - it is not the fastest solution
2. returning set from list with duplicates (did you consider only `set` instead of `list`?)
3. approach of generating only 3 types of new combinations:
   a) surrounding parentheses
   b) parentheses on the left
   c) parentheses on the right,
   which also generates many duplications and omits the symmetrical results

You can try to add one additional loop (it will not reduce problems mentioned above) but it will add the expected results to the returned set.

I modified your function by adding only one loop (my proposition is to use every position of `(` and add parentheses in the middle of that string):

```py
def get_all_parens(num):
    if num == 0:
        return []
    if num == 1:
        return ['()']
    else:
        sub_parens = get_all_parens(num - 1)
        temp = []
        for parens in sub_parens:
            temp.append('()' + parens)
            temp.append('(' + parens + ')')
            temp.append(parens + '()')

            # added loop
            last_index = 0
            for _ in range(parens.count('(')):
                temp.append(parens[:last_index] + '()' + parens[last_index:])
                last_index = parens.index('(', last_index) + 1
            # end of added loop
        return set(temp)
```

**EDIT:**

I propose linear version of that algorithm:

```py
def get_all_combinations(n):
    results = set()
    for i in range(n):
        new_results = set()
        if i == 0:
            results = {"()"}
            continue
        for it in results:
            output = set()
            last_index = 0
            for _ in range(it.count("(")):
                output.add(it[:last_index] + "()" + it[last_index:])
                last_index = it.index("(", last_index) + 1
                output.add(it[:last_index] + "()" + it[last_index:])

            new_results.update(output)
        results = new_results
    return list(results), len(results)
```